# What is the simplest way to create a music player using react-native-sounds with play & pause toggle controls in same button?

Tags: react-native, react-native-sound

I wanted to create a music player using react-native-sounds but and it was playing music flawless but the issue wast it was not stoping when i press the button, btw the button of play & pause is same.I also want it to pause when another track is playing or navigating out of that screen.

I have tried giving all type of condition's in the button to play and pause on state change,
twist is that when I use seprate button it pause and play fine but not in same button.

Comment: can you share your implementation?

Comment: I am sorry that I have deleted that code and gone with react-native-track-player for the project. The above question is written for the future developer who will face the same issue.